# Toggle Class of the button using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to enable /disable button

App.component.html : Root component triggers on change and sets initial value.

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div class="container">
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
  {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <favorite [isFavorite]="post.isFavorite" (change)="onFavoriteChange($event)" ></favorite>
</div>
<h1></h1>
<courses></courses>
</div>
```

app.component.ts : consists of root component consists on change function and post object

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello User';
  post={
   title:'Pti',
   isFavorite:true

  }
  onFavoriteChanged(isFav)
  {
   console.log("On Favorite Changed",isFav);
  }
}
```

Favorite Component

favorite.component.ts

```html
 <button  class="waves-effect waves-light btn" [class.enabled]="isSelected"
 [class.disabled]= "!isSelected" 
 (click)="onClick" >Click to {{isSelected}}</button>
```

favorite.component.ts : consists of onclick to toggled the class and emit the result

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output ,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input('isFavorite') isSelected: boolean;
   @Output() change=new EventEmitter();
   
  onClick()
  {
   console.log("CLicked");
   this.isSelected=!this.isSelected;
   this.change.emit(isSelected);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The button is not toggling. No class change and emitter too does not emit any result.

Comment: have you tried this.change.emit(); because emit is a function?

Comment: Change `(click)="onClick"` to `(click)="onClick()"` in your `favorite.component.ts`

Comment: @bryan60 yes please check edit

Comment: What about the console.log("clicked"), is it fired; and the button content {{isSelected}}, is it changed?

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`(click)="onClick"` 
to 
`(click)="onClick()"`

in  favorite.component.ts

This is the correct answer .

> Thanks @Daniel for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the description if the `onClick` function is triggered at all, but as for adjusting classes in Angular setting it directly like `[class.whatever]="expression"` also won't work for me, instead I succeeded with this form:

```
<button [ngClass]="{ 'enabled': isSelected, 'disabled': !isSelected }">
```